# Ctrl + Alt + T opening terminator as 'X-terminal-emulator', not strictly 'terminator' on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, terminator

The problem is the following: the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut opens Terminator, but as a "x-terminal-emulator" on the activity bar, and the icon is missing.

I can open Terminator as "Terminator" using the `terminator` command or icon shortcut, but it is separated from that one opened by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: "Ctrl + Alt + T shortcut is opening terminator, but as a 'X-terminal-emulator'." Can you clarify? You seem to say it does open terminator with this sentence. Or is another terminal emulator opened?

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem and found a work-around.

Open your keyboard shortcuts in settings and remove the binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> near the top.

Then scroll to the bottom and hit the button to create a new shortcut. Name it whatever you want, and make sure the command is `terminator`

[image]

Set the shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and you're all set!